# AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `comments` on serializer `Post`

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

## **In my blog app when i used to retrive all the posts I got this error.

## **

This  is the error message I got:

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `comments` on serializer `Post`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'comments'.

*I attached my code below. Help me how to get rid out of this.*

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#Abstract Start
class TimeStamp(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
class Selection(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']
#Abstract End
class Post(Selection):
    # name = title
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(_("content"))
    slug = models.SlugField(_("slug"))
    likes = models.IntegerField(_("likes"),default=0)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Comment(TimeStamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(_("comments"))
    likes = models.IntegerField(_("likes"),default=0)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from  . import models

class UserSr(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class Comment(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    user = UserSr()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        exclude = ['created_at','updated_at']

class Post(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSr()
    comments = Comment(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        exclude = ['created_at','updated_at']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .. import serializers,models

@api_view(['POST'])
def post_create(request):
    post_serializer = serializers.Post(data=request.data)
    if post_serializer.is_valid():
        post_serializer.save()
        return Response(post_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(post_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET'])
def postGet(request):
    posts = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.Post(posts,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path("blog/",views.registration_view,name='useradd'),
    path('posts/',views.postGet,name='posts'),
    path('posts/create/', views.post_create, name='post-create'),
]
```

I don't know how to get rid out of this
I've stucked it in for hours.
I refered lot of projects but i could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSr()
    comments = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ("id","author","comments")
```

You can try this.

You should not use `Comment` a model in Serializers as a field